# Using WM_GETTEXT - what to set the Size?

Tags: delphi, size, window-handles, arrays

```
Var
 PText : array[0..512] of Char;
 Handle, Child : HWND;
begin
 FillChar(PText,512,0);
 Handle := FindWindow('Notepad',nil);
 Child := FindWindowEx(Handle,0,'Edit',nil);

 Caption := IntToStr(Handle)+' - '+IntToStr(Child);

 SendMessage(Child,WM_GETTEXT,512,Integer(@PText[0]));

 ShowMessage(PText);

end;
```

I am just wondering - What should I normally set the size (Currently 512) to when using WM_GETTEXT? I guess it differs to how much text there is in the source control?

What do you recommend to set it to, when dealing with rather large ammounts of text?

Is there a way to do the same (Getting the text from a handle) without having to set sizes and such?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read the size with `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` and use the value for the buffer.

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought of that! Should I add 1 to it? I believe I saw someone do that

Comment: MSDN states for WM_GETTEXTLENGTH: The return value is the length of the text in characters, not including the terminating null character.
For WM_GETTEXT MSDN states: The maximum number of characters to be copied, including the terminating null character. 
So YES, you should add 1.

Comment: @Jeff: You may accept the answer if it is the answer of your question ;-)

Comment: @Jeff Of source you normally do this using `SetLength()` or `SetString()` and those routines don't need a +1. I would take a look at TWinControl.GetText and ape that code.

Comment: @Jeff: Please try and think about the answers you receive. A quick 30-second test could have answered your question about adding 1 or not, and you would have known a lot faster than waiting for an answer here.